# MasterWindow in WPF

Tags: wpf, windows-client

I am used to developing ASP.net web apps and now doing some exploring in WPF windows client apps.

I had been extensively using MasterPage and Themes to make my application have a uniform look.

How can I accomplish the same in WPF? What are the best practices for this?

For starters I am working on a very simple application that has two windows with a menu on the top of the window. Since this menu will appear on each window it does not make sense to copy the menu code to each window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET themeing is about the styles of the visuals. MasterPage is about controlling common parts of the visual tree. These are achieved in WPF through [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613570.aspx). Styles will give you control over the uniform look of all your visuals. Templating will allow you to build common visual trees and reuse them in different visual elements.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post from earlier in the year, it deals with issues similar to mine.
[Template Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420538/how-to-make-a-template-window-in-wpf)